# Responsive images when image rendering size in relation to screen width is unknown

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have a CMS (TYPO3) which currently outputs plain `<img>` tags. To make it responsive, I want to add `srcset` attributes with different size versions of the image.

Which leads us to the problem: With the `sizes` attribute, I can tell the browser what rendering size to assume when choosing the image version. I can give the rendering size absolutely (in `px`, `em`, etc.) or as a percentage of viewport width (in `vw`). However I cannot tell the browser to assume the image will have its parent's width (in `%`).

If I knew the parent width beforehand, I could just add it to the `sizes` attribute, if need be with some media conditions if the parent size changes due to a responsive layout (like Bootstrap columns).

Alas, I'm extending a CMS and have no control over layout or content, like:

- the page container width
- the number of columns
- design breakpoints
- column paddings and gutter widths
- any nesting of columns within columns
- any other paddings

Collecting all this information - just to find out how big the image parent is going to be - is next to impossible.

Any ideas on how I can get a responsive image that delivers the ideal size even though I don't know the final image rendering width (=parent width) at server side (neither in `px` nor `vw`)?

Though I prefer static solutions, I'm also open to JavaScript based ideas, given they fallback gracefully.

**Edit**: My question boils down to: is there some mechanism that can replace the `sizes="100%"` which is not in the standard ["to avoid confusion what it would be relative to"](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20150506/semantics.html#source-size-value)?

**Edit**:
My current solution is JS-based:

```
// this, plus some code to prevent image loading before this is executed
$('img[srcset]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('sizes', $(this).parent().width() + 'px');
})
```

I would like to not have to rely on JS to do this.

Comment: The window size is always known by the browser. You cannot get a static solution, responsive web development is about dynamics (unknowns and variables). Express the image's width using percentages and maintain aspect ratio using `auto` for the height.

Comment: @Rafael This is not about CSS styling (like `width:100%`), and by static I just mean "without JavaScript". I want to get an image version that is a good fit (not too large, not too small). But the `sizes` can only be used if I know something about how big my image is going to be, either in `px` or `vw`.

Comment: No, you are wrong, this has to do with styling. Where else do `px` and `vw` units come into play sir?

Comment: Use media queries to change the `background-image` accordingly. In between the breakpoints, the sizing should be dynamic. Do you understand?

Comment: @Rafael I don't want background images, but an [`<img>` tag with a srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Example_4_Using_the_srcset_and_sizes_attributes). The syntax is like CSS, but it's not CSS. What would you have me write in the `sizes` attribute if I don't know any `px` or `vw` value that I can assume for my image width?

Comment: If you don't want to use background images, use multiple `img` tags with different `src` and have them display according to the defined breakpoints. I don't know how else to get this notion across to you. You will have to use media queries one way or another.

Comment: My suggestion would be to forget about generating media in multiple sizes statically, and also about CSS-only solution. Invest a bit of time in setting up your media server so it can return dynamically resized images, with proper caching and all that, and use a JS solution that will request an image with exact width of the parent scaled by device pixel ratio. Use something like this, for example: https://github.com/ericuldall/nginx-dynamic-resize There are also services that do this, but some of then require backend support (signed URLs, etc).

Comment: @hayavuk A compelling idea, thank you. Some caveats though: 1. it would have to be a local and PHP based solution, as TYPO3 CMS supports different webservers. 2. it would depend on JavaScript as well as far as I can tell. In fact without JS there will be no images at all. For this project the approach micght be an overkill, but I definitely will have to remember it for some other time

Comment: If you serve TYPO3 CMS behind a nginx, then this can work. It requires no PHP as it can be done with an nginx extension and some client-side code. The basic idea is that you serve the <img> tag with some lower or medium resolution image (one that won't look too crappy w/o JS), and then you fire up some JS to fine-tune the result. It's certainly not a light solution, but if the site is primarily media-oriented, then it's a worthwhile investment and reduces the total payload greatly over the time.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

#### Use srcset

Your use case is exactly what `srcset` was designed for. The `<source>` image sizes are known ahead of time; the container size is known at run time; you define pixel ranges exactly like CSS `@media` queries to tell the browser which `<source>` to use for a given container size.

The media query is relative to the viewport, not the container (as with CSS media queries) so you do have to do some math to decide which image you want to use for a container's expected size relative to that viewport.   (I believe the reason for this complexity is so you can set images depending on [screen density](https://www.w3.org/TR/respimg-usecases/#device-pixel-ratio-based-selection) as well, but don't quote me on that.)

The idea is to set the size of the image externally, relative to a container, then use srcset to select an image appropriate for that container's expected size given that viewport size.

(StackOverflow's code snippet makes this difficult to see because it draws the sample inside a fixed-size frame; the most you can see is the image source not changing when you resize the div, which maybe isn't the most compelling demo ever.  To try out the viewport resize you'll need to copy the code into a new window).

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" resizable>
  <picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 100px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/500x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/600x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 700px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/700x150">
    <source media="(max-width: 800px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/800x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10x10" width="100%">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Browser support is currently [incomplete](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) (IE and Edge are, as usual, the culprits) but [polyfills](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) exist.

#### Use background-image

...which can be changed using media queries.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  .container {
    background-image: url('big.jpg');
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    background-image: url('small.jpg');
  }
}
```

This is universally supported, but requires that your CMS be able to generate CSS rules along with the HTML.

Comment: beware; experimental solution, nonstandard.

Comment: It dates back to 2014, is included in the current HTML5 working standard http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element and is supported in most major browsers, polyfilled in the remainder.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks for your answer! However one question: The @media widths in both solutions refer to screen widths, not container widths, correct?. Since I don't know at all in what relation the image display size is going to be relative to the screen width (don't know the number of columns etc.), I can't assign any sensible image versions to the media queries. My question boils down to: is there some mechanism that can replace the `sizes="100%"` which is not in the standard ["to avoid confusion"](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-html51-20150506/semantics.html#source-size-value)?

Comment: @Josta Sorry, that was sloppy of me, you're right about the viewport vs container thing. I've updated the answer to expand on that

Comment: @DanielBeck on the updated answer: Thanks for the snippet. It show that the browser chooses the version only by screen size. If I knew ahead of time what width my container would be for a specific media range, I could use that (e.g. if container had 50% screen width in the 0-500px range, I could use ` <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150">`). Sadly I simply don't know anything about the container width ahead of time. I gather from your answer that in this case, I can't do anything?